# What is serialization?

Tags: feature-selection

A fictional Broadway show has 3 shows every Saturday.  Tickets are valid for a particular show and enumerated seat.   The process of encoding the showtime and seat number is a unique.

Is the process of encoding the notion of a time and seat an example  serialization? enumeration?  If not, what?

Comment: Serialisation means that they can be executed either in a serial order or even though there's conflicts, they are conflict serializable... Note serial and serializable aren't the same